# Laravel push notification token: use Eloquent or Query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, push-notification, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table 'Token', a `'User'` can have multiple `'Token'`, and a `'Token'` can only belong to 1x `'User'`, I can use `hasMany()` & `belongsTo()` for this relationship, but everytime a user logout from android&iOS, the token row record will be removed, and on User login, a new token record will be added into the table, so the incrementing primary key will be consumed and wasted, so I am wondering if I should remove the primary key and use Laravel Query Builder instead? since Laravel Eloquent cant work correctly without a primary key?

Comment: Is it required to remove the record from the table? Else you could set token to null on logout and update on login plus make a token record if it doesn't exist yet. Seems more simple to me.

Comment: what if I have multiple null records? so if a 'User' have 3 different token for android GCM and logout on 2x, then I should NULL the 2 records? and if later the same user login again I will update one of the NULL records and if no NULL record is found it create a new record?

Comment: I would say you have only one token per (token type?). Update the record that is binded with the token and with what kind of token it is as where condition. For type you could use a ENUM maybe but i'm not sure how complex the situation is. As I'm not sure now why an user can have more than 1 token.

Comment: User can login from multiple Android or iOS device, different device will each generate a different token, so If a User is currently logged in to 2x android or ios devices, when a GCM/APNS push notification is sent, both devices will receive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one of the solutions you can use.

Make the Token Table look something like this:

---

**Token Table**

id | user_id | device | token

---

In device you can store an unique value of the device you're referring to.

**A few things regarding the token table:**

- Insert a new token record if one doesn't exist yet with current device. (Set token)
- If an user logouts the unique device set token to null (Update)
- If an user login again update the token value from null to the token value

Comment: I see, so if a user login with 3 android devices, and later logout from 2, 2x records will be set to NULL, so next time, when the same user login I will need to find if records with token=NULL exist first, and If it does, I will UPDATE, else CREATE a new record row?

Comment: @yeln Yep I think you got it now. The notifications you can send to all logged on users where token != null.

Comment: @yeln if this is a solution for your problem can you accept the answer?